# Convert array to dateformat

Tags: php

How could I implement date() function in my array $date_formats?

Code:

```
$date_formats = array('F j, Y', 'Y-m-d', 'm/d/Y', 'd/m/Y');

foreach ( $date_formats as $format ) {

echo "<label><input type='radio' value'" . ($format) . "'";
if (get_setting('dateformat') === $format) {
    echo " checked='checked'";
}
echo " name='dateformat'>" . $format . "</label><br>"; 
}
```

I hope someone could help, thanks in advance.

Comment: you just need an equal sign after value in the first echo

Comment: Yes but my label still shows the date format and not the actual date.

Comment: That's because you missed the date() Function. Wrap your output like this: `".date($format)."`

Comment: @mimo well I made that too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the current date formatted in each of the ways indicated on your array you have but to call array_map with "date" as the callback

```
$date_formats = array('F j, Y', 'Y-m-d', 'm/d/Y', 'd/m/Y');
$dates = array_map("date", $date_formats);
```

If you wanted to specify a particular date that would require defining your own callback as in

```
$when = strtotime("last monday");
$date_formats = array('F j, Y', 'Y-m-d', 'm/d/Y', 'd/m/Y');
$dates = array_map(function ($dt) use ($when){ 
                       return date($dt, $when); 
                   }, 
                   $date_formats);
```

To see the code in action check out [here](http://3v4l.org/skFcC)

From there its a trivial call to array_combine to associate the keys and values together then output your html

```
$dts = array_combine($date_formats, $dates);
foreach ( $dts as $format=>$date ) {    
    echo "<label><input type='radio' value'" . ($format) . "'";
    echo " name='dateformat'>" . $date . "</label><br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Perfect and thanks `array_map` solved my problem :-)